# Running PowerShell Script on Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, task

I've looked at all PowerShell script on task scheduler answers in other questions and have not been able to find one that will solve this.

I have tried running the PowerShell Script straight through task scheduler using:

```
       powershell.exe -file c:\path_to_your_script\script.ps1
```

As well as creating a batch to run the PowerShell script.

The PowerShell Script works perfectly find when its ran on its own as well as when ran through the batch manually.

It opens an excel, refreshes it, saves, and closes.

I'm unable to successfully schedule this through the task handler.

Any advice?

Thank you for your help

Edited:

@luke this is the export of the settings for task scheduler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
<Date>2015-05-11T12:40:51.6084684</Date>
<Author>----------</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
 <TimeTrigger>
  <Repetition>
    <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
    <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
  </Repetition>
  <StartBoundary>2015-05-11T12:30:00</StartBoundary>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
</TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
<Principal id="Author">
  <UserId>------\Administrator</UserId>
  <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
  <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
</Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
<MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
<StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
<AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
<StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
<RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
<IdleSettings>
  <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
  <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
</IdleSettings>
<AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
<RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
<WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
<ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
<Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
<Exec>
  <Command>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
  <Arguments>/q /c "C:\Users\---------\Documents\PowerBI\PowerShell\RunExcelRefreshingScriptPowerShell2.bat"</Arguments>
</Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Problems with running a script as a scheduled task are almost always related to either access rights for the account that the task is running under or profile differences for that account.

Comment: In the Task Scheduler, what is the value of "Last Run Result" for this task?

Comment: @EBGreen the local administrator account is being used. Thank you

Comment: @SamuelProut  are you asking about the correlation id? Can't seem to find the "Last Run Result" under the history tab. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a DCOM Identity issue. Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25210194/3905079)?

Comment: @briantist, thank you for your comment. Tried that and had no success

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue where I created a scheduled task to run a PowerShell script I created. I found that if you add the path to the Powershell.exe (ie: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) in the Program/script window and the path to your actual PowerShell script (ie: D:\Scripts\PowershellScript.ps1)(See Example Below) in the Arguments window it will work. You would also have to check the Server's PowerShell execution policy to make sure it's set to "unrestricted".  You can also try adding it as an argument (-ExecutionPolicy Bypass).
I hope this will help someone.
Example:
[Task to Run PowerShell Scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgT5J.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

can you provide an export of the settings of the Task Schedule without the username or password.

I have many powershells running through Task Scheduler and not a single issue because I have my scheduler call the bat which starts the powershell.

[image: TaskSchedulerLastRunResult]

and this is where you will find the last run result.

Comment: Luke, the last run result was (0x41306), it stayed running forever and I had to end it. I will post the export of the settings in an answer because it was too long to post here.

Comment: With your export I noticed that you have it saved in a user folder, is it saved in the user folder of the user that you are trying to run the task under? and I can't find it but did you also have the  "Run whether the user is logged on or not" checked?

Also have you tried running it under "SYSTEM"

Comment: It is not saved under the local administrator. But wouldn't the local administrator have access to all users and their files? It's worth a try. I'll let you know how that goes. Thank you Luke

Comment: @JoaquinCorrales Yes the Admin would have access but it requires elevation to get into another users folder, I would suggest making a folder in the root of c:\ for your scripts to run out of.

Comment: the folder has been put in the root and it still stays running indefinitely. Thank you Luke

Comment: Did it complete the task that you expected it to?

Comment: manually opening the batch or powershell script does the job but the task scheduler doesn't. Not even putting it in the root

Comment: Okay so your script calls excel to open it and then saves and closes it, I am not sure if excel can be "Opened" but not visible. you could try running it under System and see if that works

Comment: running It under system lets it run successfully with a last run result of 0x0 but the excel file remains untouched. Luke, what does your action tab consist of?

Comment: It is just a action to run the .bat file that starts my script. could you have it run at any user log on and see if that fixes it?