# What does one need to run Microsoft Word from service environment

Tags: powershell, service, ms-word, activex

I need to start Microsoft Word (2010 and newer) headless from a service in order to convert a document to (save it as) a PDF file.

I've tried Powershell and ActiveX (both called from a C++ program ) so far to no avail.

**Details**

When I run the application as a normal user program under my account, everything runs as it is supposed to, i.e. I get the converted file and program exits normally (with both solutions listed below).

When run as a service (no difference whether run under system account or my account), Word spits out some very cryptic error messages (unfortunately translated into the Windows language). What I've been able to understand is that the %TEMP% path is inaccessible or the working file could not be opened. I have therefore set the environment variable (to a folder accessible for system with all permissions allowed), but it didn't help.

I've also tried and failed to find any piece of relevant documentation as to what Word needs to be able to work.

It doesn't seem to matter whether the ActiveX is run directly from the service or as an external process started by means of Windows system call.

I do the same with PowerPoint with no problems at all, but I don't seem to be able to persuade Word into cooperation.

**PowerShell**

```
$file=$args[0] 
$outputFile=$args[1] 

$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application 
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($file)
$doc.SaveAs([ref] $outputFile, [ref] 17)

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

**ActiveX (called from Qt)**

```
// pointer checks etc omitted for brevity

CoInitialize(0);
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

// get word-application-object
QAxObject* app = new QAxObject("Word.Application", this);

// get documents-object
QAxObject* docs = app->querySubObject("Documents");


// create new doc-object by opening an file
QAxObject* doc = docs->querySubObject("Open (const QString&)", QString("D:/Path/To/Files/Test.docx"));

// save document as pdf (=17)
doc->dynamicCall("SaveAs2 (const QString&,int)", QString("D:/Path/To/Files/Test.pdf"), 17);

// close word
app->dynamicCall("Quit (void)");
```

**The question**

What does one need in order to run Word for the conversion to PDF from a Service? Or where can one Find the relevant documentation?

Comment: Word is a GUI application, and services don't have a desktop to display that UI. IOW, you can't.

Comment: @KenWhite The same, if not more, is true for PowerPoint, and PowerPoint _does_ work this way. What's more, when run as a headless application (and not service), no GUI whatsoever is produced, and the conversion _does_ work.

Comment: Please consult this KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. Server-side use of Office is not supported and not recommended. You can use Word Automation Services to convert Word documents to PDF or license a third-party tool for the conversion or build your own converter that works directly with the Office Open XML file format.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for the link. Doesn't look good for me, but at least there is some firm ground from where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task Scheduler doesn't execute batch file properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209037/task-scheduler-doesnt-execute-batch-file-properly)

Comment: @PavelPetrman [try the solution in the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25210194/3905079); Cindy is right and automation on the server is not supported or recommended but I was also in a situation where the "right" way wasn't a good fit.

Comment: Just in case Word is like Excel, you might want to be aware of this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819825/powershell-scheduled-task-to-run-script-with-excel-com-object/35820829#35820829

Comment: Most likely you're facing Session 0 isolation here. Services run in session 0 and don't have a desktop. However, Word being an interactive application requires a desktop. You would have to create a desktop yourself (using the `CreateDesktop` API). Though not completely impossible, this is a lot of work, unsupported by Microsoft and very difficult to get right. You might be better off using SharePoint's Word Automation Services or a third-party application such as Aspose to get the job done.

Comment: As mentoined by Dirk Vollmar services run in an isolated environment in the local system account (session 0), this has been introduced in Windows Vista.
If your service needs to run a program in a user's context, you'll need to use CreateProcessAsUser(). Before you can do this, you need to:

- Get the curent interactive user session using WTSEnumerateSessions()
- Impersonate the user via WTSQueryUserToken(), DuplicationTokenEx() and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()
- Setup process environment via CreateEnvironmentBlock() and filling correct values into STARTUP_INFORMATION